# How to improve performance of ngRepeat over a huge dataset (angular.js)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a huge dataset of several thousand rows with around 10 fields each, about 2MBs of data. I need to display it in the browser. Most straightforward approach (fetch data, put it into `$scope`, let `ng-repeat=""` do its job) works fine, but it freezes the browser for about half of a minute when it starts inserting nodes into DOM. How should I approach this problem?

One option is to append rows to `$scope` incrementally and wait for `ngRepeat` to finish inserting one chunk into DOM before moving to the next one. But AFAIK ngRepeat does not report back when it finishes "repeating", so it's going to be ugly.

Other option is to split data on the server into pages and fetch them in multiple requests, but that's even uglier.

I looked through Angular documentation in search of something like `ng-repeat="data in dataset" ng-repeat-steps="500"`, but found nothing. I am fairly new to Angular ways, so it is possible that I am missing the point completely. What are the best practices at this?

Comment: Do you really want to display ALL rows? What about displaying only that many rows the user can see. e.g. you could use ````limitTo````to display only 20 items: ````<p ng-repeat="data in dataset | limitTo:20">{{data}}</p>```` This shows only 20 items. Then you could use pages and show the next 10 items or something like that. :)

Comment: for that "report back when it finishes 'repeating'" thing you could use a custom directive in addition to ng-repeat. (see here the selected answer)   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471129/angularjs-ng-repeat-finish-event

Comment: refer this question it will surely help you.

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25481021/angular-ng-class-performance-issue-when-too-many-elements-in-dom

Answer (score 162, accepted):

I agree with @AndreM96 that the best approach is to display only a limited amount of rows, faster and better UX, this could be done with a pagination or with an infinite scroll.

Infinite scroll with Angular is really simple with [limitTo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) filter. You just have to set the initial limit and when the user asks for more data (I am using a button for simplicity) you increment the limit.

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="d in data | limitTo:totalDisplayed"><td>{{d}}</td></tr>
</table>
<button class="btn" ng-click="loadMore()">Load more</button>

//the controller
$scope.totalDisplayed = 20;

$scope.loadMore = function () {
  $scope.totalDisplayed += 20;  
};

$scope.data = data;
```

Here is a [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/oricad/1/edit).

This approach could be a problem for phones because usually they lag when scrolling a lot of data, so in this case I think a pagination fits better.

To do it you will need the limitTo filter and also a custom filter to define the starting point of the data being displayed.

Here is a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ilugum/2/edit) with a pagination.

Comment: Nice alternative!!! You know any method to use if I am bound to show all the items. any loading sign or one after one insertion into DOM or something?

Comment: Do you mean display a "loading..." or something while the data is being fetched?

Comment: Can you provide me an example to load data on scrolling ? I dont want user to click on load more data button, rather It would be better to load data when user reaches at the end of scroll. I tried to find the things but didnt ind any proper solution with angular.

Comment: will a filter now only search through the contents of the array limited by `limitTo`, or will it search through the original big array?

Comment: @Sumit limitTo will be applied to ng-repeat scope, so the result will be a new array which will be passed to ng-repeat, your data array still the same and you can still search all content.

Comment: if the user presses loadmore 10 times and every press add 100 more items, how can this improve the performance?

Comment: @hariszaman I agree. This doesn't improve performance. It just delays the poor performance. Infinite scroll will get you into trouble unless you are virtualizing it (which ui-grid does).

Comment: Hariszaman You might want to reconsider your app design if for every loadMore request you must push 100's of new items to the view, going through a list with 1000’s of items doesn't feel very human, also, [throttling](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.1#throttle) is a way to solve the problem with multiple consecutive clicks, anyway, if you must display thousands of items, I agree wth richard that ui-grid is probably a good tool.

Comment: Infinite scroll is not working in iOS but working fine on web . Did i miss anything for iOS ?

Answer (score 42):

The hottest - and arguably most scalable - approach to overcoming these challenges with large datasets is embodied by the approach of [Ionic's collectionRepeat directive](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/collectionRepeat/) and of other implementations like it. A fancy term for this is ['occlusion culling'](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OcclusionCulling.html), but you can sum it up as: don't just limit the count of rendered DOM elements to an arbitrary (but still high) paginated number like 50, 100, 500... instead, *limit only to as many elements as the user can see*.

If you do something like what's commonly known as "infinite scrolling", you're reducing the *initial* DOM count somewhat, but it bloats quickly after a couple refreshes, because all those new elements are just tacked on at the bottom. Scrolling comes to a crawl, because scrolling is all about element count. There's nothing infinite about it.

Whereas, the `collectionRepeat` approach is to use only as many elements as will fit in viewport, and then *recycle them*. As one element rotates out of view, it's detached from the render tree, refilled with data for a new item in the list, then reattached to the render tree at the other end of the list. This is the fastest way known to man to get new information in and out of the DOM, making use of a limited set of existing elements, rather than the traditional cycle of create/destroy... create/destroy. Using this approach, you can truly implement an *infinite* scroll.

Note that you don't have to use Ionic to use/hack/adapt `collectionRepeat`, or any other tool like it. That's why they call it open-source. :-) (That said, the Ionic team is doing some pretty ingenious things, worthy of your attention.)

---

There's at least one [excellent example](http://jlongster.com/Removing-User-Interface-Complexity,-or-Why-React-is-Awesome) of doing something very similar in React. Only instead of recycling the elements with updated content, you're simply choosing not to render anything in the tree that's not in view. It's blazing fast on 5000 items, although their very simple POC implementation allows a bit of flicker...

---

Also... to echo some of the other posts, using `track by` is seriously helpful, even with smaller datasets. Consider it mandatory.

Comment: Awesome idea by the Ionic team. I wonder if that came from how native views are rendered?

Comment: For instance, UITableView in iOS use the same approach to render large data sets. I think this is a common approach used in many native views.

Answer (score 38):

I recommend to see this:

- http://blog.scalyr.com/2013/10/angularjs-1200ms-to-35ms/

**Optimizing AngularJS: 1200ms to 35ms**

they made a new directive by optimizing ng-repeat at 4 parts:

> Optimization#1: Cache DOM elements
>
> Optimization#2: Aggregate watchers
>
> Optimization#3: Defer element creation
>
> Optimization#4: Bypass watchers for hidden elements

the project is here on github:

- https://github.com/scalyr/angular

## Usage:

1- include these files in your single-page app:

- core.js
- scalyr.js
- slyEvaluate.js
- slyRepeat.js

2- add module dependency:

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['sly']);
```

3- replace ng-repeat

```
<tr sly-repeat="m in rows"> .....<tr>
```

ENjoY!

Comment: I think this scalyr.js already includes the others files. Because  is the result of build script.

Comment: I tried to use Scalyr but the filter doesnt work.

<tr sly-repeat="option in main.customers | filter: search_input | limitTo:20">

Comment: This is extremely helpful. I'm using it on an AngularJS 1.6 app where the client wants to see lots of cells of data (normally I design forms with paging/reduced data elements but the client needs to compare lots of data at once). So far the grid of cells has gone from unusable to perfectly fine because of this library. But this lib was written way back in the AngularJS 1.2 days so I'll be testing carefully looking for problems.

Comment: From what I can tell at this time the gatedScope.js file (323 lines) is the only one that needs to be verified to be runable on more current versions of AngularJS. This pull request is notable: https://github.com/karser/angular/commit/771748b4de4ff46b86c50a63046cc4063bc406e7. It updates the signature rootScope.$new.

Comment: included all four js files and used `sly-repeat` but nothing helped me the results are still slow and browser lags also getting violations `[Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 54ms`, `[Violation] 'scroll' handler took 1298ms`

Answer (score 16):

Beside all the above hints like track by and smaller loops, this one also helped me a lot

```
<span ng-bind="::stock.name"></span>
```

this piece of code would print the name once it has been loaded, and stop watching it after that. Similarly, for ng-repeats, it could be used as

```
<div ng-repeat="stock in ::ctrl.stocks">{{::stock.name}}</div>
```

however it only works for AngularJS version 1.3 and higher. 
From
http://www.befundoo.com/blog/optimizing-ng-repeat-in-angularjs/

Comment: Do you need the `::` on the repeat as well as the expression? The docs say otherwise, but I'm not sure of way to test that this is working. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

Comment: `::` is redundant. ng-bind is used to achieve one-way data binding.

Answer (score 13):

You can use "track by" to increase the performance:

```
<div ng-repeat="a in arr track by a.trackingKey">
```

Faster than:

```
<div ng-repeat="a in arr">
```

ref:https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/angularjs-performance-large-applications

Comment: This doesn't really help for performance. See http://jsperf.com/ng-repeat-vs-ng-repeat-with-trace-by-id

Comment: with track by you don't track the array element from the beginning each time you get new data. as a result this improve performance.

Comment: This is useful only when the data in the ng-repeat changes. For initial load, it might not create a performance improvement.

Answer (score 11):

If all your rows have equal height, you should definitely take a look at the virtualizing ng-repeat: http://kamilkp.github.io/angular-vs-repeat/

This [demo](http://kamilkp.github.io/angular-vs-repeat/) looks very promising (and it supports inertial scrolling)

Comment: Scroll performance on mobile is not acceptable (scroll events does not fire on mobile iOS (only up from 8)

Answer (score 11):

**Virtual scrolling** is another way to improve scrolling performance when dealing with huge lists and large dataset.

One way to implement this is by using [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/) `md-virtual-repeat` as it is demonstrated on this [Demo with 50,000 items](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/virtualRepeat)

Taken straight from the documentation of virtual repeat:

> Virtual repeat is a limited substitute for ng-repeat that renders only enough dom nodes to fill the container and recycling them as the user scrolls.

Comment: Wow, I think this is the most interesting answer. Will this works with older version of angular? (e.g. ver 1.2)

Comment: @ThariqNugrohotomo Please note that using Angular Material requires the use of Angular 1.3.x or higher. 
Also thanks for the support, i am really amazed by virtual repeat as well and we already using it on a mobile app that displays a really long list of results.

Answer (score 9):

Rule No.1: Never let the user wait for anything.

That in mind a life growing page that needs 10seconds appears way faster than waiting 3 seconds on before a blank screen and get all at once.

So instead of **make** the page fast, just let the page **appear** to be fast, even if the final result is slower:

```
function applyItemlist(items){
    var item = items.shift();
    if(item){
        $timeout(function(){
            $scope.items.push(item);
            applyItemlist(items);
        }, 0); // <-- try a little gap of 10ms
    }
}
```

The code above let appear the list to be growing row-by-row, and is always slower than render all at once. **But for the user** it appears to be faster.

Comment: how to use this function in html page?

Answer (score 8):

Another version @Steffomio

Instead of adding each item individually we can add items by chunks.

```
// chunks function from here: 
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks#11764168
var chunks = chunk(folders, 100);

//immediate display of our first set of items
$scope.items = chunks[0];

var delay = 100;
angular.forEach(chunks, function(value, index) {
    delay += 100;

    // skip the first chuck
    if( index > 0 ) {
        $timeout(function() {
            Array.prototype.push.apply($scope.items,value);
        }, delay);
    }       
});
```

Comment: Interesting idea.  I tried this on an array of ~8000 elements, and while it did make the page more responsive initially, it became less responsive after each chunk.

Comment: This was a huge problem on my app after having more than 500 items. I suggest pagination or infinite loading instead.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes what happened,**you get the data from server (or back-end) in few ms** (for example I'm I am assuming it 100ms) but **it takes more time to display in our web page** (let's say it is taking 900ms to display).

So, What is happening here is 800ms It is taking just to render web page.

What I have done in my web application is, I have used **pagination** (or you can use *infinite scrolling* also) to display list of data. Let's say I am showing 50 data/page.

So I will not load render all the data at once,only 50 data I am loading initially which takes only 50ms (I'm assuming here).

so total time here decreased from 900ms to 150ms, once user request next page then display next 50 data and so on.

**Hope this will help you to improve the performance. All the best**

Answer (score 0):

```
Created a directive (ng-repeat with lazy loading)
```

which loads data when it reaches to bottom of the page and remove half of the previously loaded data and when it reaches to top of the div again previous data(depending upon on page number) will be loaded removing half of the current data So on DOM at a time only limited data is present which may leads to better performance instead of rendering whole data on load.

HTML CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.20"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="ListController">
  <div class="row customScroll" id="customTable" datafilter pagenumber="pageNumber" data="rowData" searchdata="searchdata" itemsPerPage="{{itemsPerPage}}"  totaldata="totalData"   selectedrow="onRowSelected(row,row.index)"  style="height:300px;overflow-y: auto;padding-top: 5px">

    <!--<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 assign-list" ng-repeat="row in CRGC.rowData track by $index | orderBy:sortField:sortReverse | filter:searchFish">-->
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 pdl0 assign-list" style="padding:10px" ng-repeat="row in rowData" ng-hide="row[CRGC.columns[0].id]=='' && row[CRGC.columns[1].id]==''">
        <!--col1-->

        <div ng-click ="onRowSelected(row,row.index)"> <span>{{row["sno"]}}</span> <span>{{row["id"]}}</span> <span>{{row["name"]}}</span></div>
      <!--   <div class="border_opacity"></div> -->
    </div>

</div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Angular CODE:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
var x;
ListController.$inject = ['$scope', '$timeout', '$q', '$templateCache'];

function ListController($scope, $timeout, $q, $templateCache) {
  $scope.itemsPerPage = 40;
  $scope.lastPage = 0;
  $scope.maxPage = 100;
  $scope.data = [];
  $scope.pageNumber = 0;


  $scope.makeid = function() {
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return text;
  }


  $scope.DataFormFunction = function() {
      var arrayObj = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.itemsPerPage*$scope.maxPage; i++) {
          arrayObj.push({
              sno: i + 1,
              id: Math.random() * 100,
              name: $scope.makeid()
          });
      }
      $scope.totalData = arrayObj;
      $scope.totalData = $scope.totalData.filter(function(a,i){ a.index = i; return true; })
      $scope.rowData = $scope.totalData.slice(0, $scope.itemsperpage);
    }
  $scope.DataFormFunction();

  $scope.onRowSelected = function(row,index){
    console.log(row,index);
  }

}

angular.module('plunker').controller('ListController', ListController).directive('datafilter', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EAC',
    scope: {
      data: '=',
      totalData: '=totaldata',
      pageNumber: '=pagenumber',
      searchdata: '=',
      defaultinput: '=',
      selectedrow: '&',
      filterflag: '=',
      totalFilterData: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
      //scope.pageNumber = 0;
      var tempData = angular.copy(scope.totalData);
      scope.totalPageLength = Math.ceil(scope.totalData.length / +attr.itemsperpage);
      console.log(scope.totalData);
      scope.data = scope.totalData.slice(0, attr.itemsperpage);
      elem.on('scroll', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
      //  var scrollHeight = angular.element('#customTable').scrollTop();
      var scrollHeight = document.getElementById("customTable").scrollTop
        /*if(scope.filterflag && scope.pageNumber != 0){
        scope.data = scope.totalFilterData;
        scope.pageNumber = 0;
        angular.element('#customTable').scrollTop(0);
        }*/
        if (scrollHeight < 100) {
          if (!scope.filterflag) {
            scope.scrollUp();
          }
        }
        if (angular.element(this).scrollTop() + angular.element(this).innerHeight() >= angular.element(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
          console.log("scroll bottom reached");
          if (!scope.filterflag) {
            scope.scrollDown();
          }
        }
        scope.$apply(scope.data);

      });

      /*
       * Scroll down data append function
       */
      scope.scrollDown = function() {
          if (scope.defaultinput == undefined || scope.defaultinput == "") { //filter data append condition on scroll
            scope.totalDataCompare = scope.totalData;
          } else {
            scope.totalDataCompare = scope.totalFilterData;
          }
          scope.totalPageLength = Math.ceil(scope.totalDataCompare.length / +attr.itemsperpage);
          if (scope.pageNumber < scope.totalPageLength - 1) {
            scope.pageNumber++;
            scope.lastaddedData = scope.totalDataCompare.slice(scope.pageNumber * attr.itemsperpage, (+attr.itemsperpage) + (+scope.pageNumber * attr.itemsperpage));
            scope.data = scope.totalDataCompare.slice(scope.pageNumber * attr.itemsperpage - 0.5 * (+attr.itemsperpage), scope.pageNumber * attr.itemsperpage);
            scope.data = scope.data.concat(scope.lastaddedData);
            scope.$apply(scope.data);
            if (scope.pageNumber < scope.totalPageLength) {
              var divHeight = $('.assign-list').outerHeight();
              if (!scope.moveToPositionFlag) {
                angular.element('#customTable').scrollTop(divHeight * 0.5 * (+attr.itemsperpage));
              } else {
                scope.moveToPositionFlag = false;
              }
            }


          }
        }
        /*
         * Scroll up data append function
         */
      scope.scrollUp = function() {
          if (scope.defaultinput == undefined || scope.defaultinput == "") { //filter data append condition on scroll
            scope.totalDataCompare = scope.totalData;
          } else {
            scope.totalDataCompare = scope.totalFilterData;
          }
          scope.totalPageLength = Math.ceil(scope.totalDataCompare.length / +attr.itemsperpage);
          if (scope.pageNumber > 0) {
            this.positionData = scope.data[0];
            scope.data = scope.totalDataCompare.slice(scope.pageNumber * attr.itemsperpage - 0.5 * (+attr.itemsperpage), scope.pageNumber * attr.itemsperpage);
            var position = +attr.itemsperpage * scope.pageNumber - 1.5 * (+attr.itemsperpage);
            if (position < 0) {
              position = 0;
            }
            scope.TopAddData = scope.totalDataCompare.slice(position, (+attr.itemsperpage) + position);
            scope.pageNumber--;
            var divHeight = $('.assign-list').outerHeight();
            if (position != 0) {
              scope.data = scope.TopAddData.concat(scope.data);
              scope.$apply(scope.data);
              angular.element('#customTable').scrollTop(divHeight * 1 * (+attr.itemsperpage));
            } else {
              scope.data = scope.TopAddData;
              scope.$apply(scope.data);
              angular.element('#customTable').scrollTop(divHeight * 0.5 * (+attr.itemsperpage));
            }
          }
        }
    }
  };
});
```

[Demo with directive](https://plnkr.co/edit/7aJGx7yXznCAa0lnFYPo?p=preview)

```
Another Solution: If you using UI-grid in the project then  same implementation is there in UI grid with infinite-scroll.
```

Depending upon height of the division it loads the data and upon scroll new data will be append and previous data will be removed.

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid/master/ui-grid.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.20"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-grid/4.0.6/ui-grid.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="ListController">
     <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 15px">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class='btn btn-primary' ng-click="resetList()">RESET</button>
      </div>
      <input class="form-control" ng-model="search" ng-change="abc()">
    </div>

    <div data-ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid" ui-grid-selection  data-ui-grid-infinite-scroll style="height :400px"></div>

    <button ng-click="getProductList()">Submit</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

Angular Code:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.grid', 'ui.grid.infiniteScroll', 'ui.grid.selection']);
var x;
angular.module('plunker').controller('ListController', ListController);
ListController.$inject = ['$scope', '$timeout', '$q', '$templateCache'];

function ListController($scope, $timeout, $q, $templateCache) {
    $scope.itemsPerPage = 200;
    $scope.lastPage = 0;
    $scope.maxPage = 5;
    $scope.data = [];

    var request = {
        "startAt": "1",
        "noOfRecords": $scope.itemsPerPage
    };
    $templateCache.put('ui-grid/selectionRowHeaderButtons',
        "<div class=\"ui-grid-selection-row-header-buttons \" ng-class=\"{'ui-grid-row-selected': row.isSelected}\" ><input style=\"margin: 0; vertical-align: middle\" type=\"checkbox\" ng-model=\"row.isSelected\" ng-click=\"row.isSelected=!row.isSelected;selectButtonClick(row, $event)\">&nbsp;</div>"
    );


    $templateCache.put('ui-grid/selectionSelectAllButtons',
        "<div class=\"ui-grid-selection-row-header-buttons \" ng-class=\"{'ui-grid-all-selected': grid.selection.selectAll}\" ng-if=\"grid.options.enableSelectAll\"><input style=\"margin: 0; vertical-align: middle\" type=\"checkbox\" ng-model=\"grid.selection.selectAll\" ng-click=\"grid.selection.selectAll=!grid.selection.selectAll;headerButtonClick($event)\"></div>"
    );

    $scope.gridOptions = {
        infiniteScrollDown: true,
        enableSorting: false,
        enableRowSelection: true,
        enableSelectAll: true,
        //enableFullRowSelection: true,
        columnDefs: [{
            field: 'sno',
            name: 'sno'
        }, {
            field: 'id',
            name: 'ID'
        }, {
            field: 'name',
            name: 'My Name'
        }],
        data: 'data',
        onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
            gridApi.infiniteScroll.on.needLoadMoreData($scope, $scope.loadMoreData);
            $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
        }
    };
    $scope.gridOptions.multiSelect = true;
    $scope.makeid = function() {
        var text = "";
        var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

        return text;
    }
    $scope.abc = function() {
        var a = $scope.search;
        x = $scope.searchData;
        $scope.data = x.filter(function(arr, y) {
            return arr.name.indexOf(a) > -1
        })
        console.log($scope.data);
        if ($scope.gridApi.grid.selection.selectAll)
            $timeout(function() {
                $scope.gridApi.selection.selectAllRows();
            }, 100);
    }


    $scope.loadMoreData = function() {
        var promise = $q.defer();
        if ($scope.lastPage < $scope.maxPage) {
            $timeout(function() {
                var arrayObj = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.itemsPerPage; i++) {
                    arrayObj.push({
                        sno: i + 1,
                        id: Math.random() * 100,
                        name: $scope.makeid()
                    });
                }

                if (!$scope.search) {
                    $scope.lastPage++;
                    $scope.data = $scope.data.concat(arrayObj);
                    $scope.gridApi.infiniteScroll.dataLoaded();
                    console.log($scope.data);
                    $scope.searchData = $scope.data;
                    // $scope.data = $scope.searchData;
                    promise.resolve();
                    if ($scope.gridApi.grid.selection.selectAll)
                        $timeout(function() {
                            $scope.gridApi.selection.selectAllRows();
                        }, 100);
                }


            }, Math.random() * 1000);
        } else {
            $scope.gridApi.infiniteScroll.dataLoaded();
            promise.resolve();
        }
        return promise.promise;
    };

    $scope.loadMoreData();

    $scope.getProductList = function() {

        if ($scope.gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows().length > 0) {
            $scope.gridOptions.data = $scope.resultSimulatedData;
            $scope.mySelectedRows = $scope.gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows(); //<--Property undefined error here
            console.log($scope.mySelectedRows);
            //alert('Selected Row: ' + $scope.mySelectedRows[0].id + ', ' + $scope.mySelectedRows[0].name + '.');
        } else {
            alert('Select a row first');
        }
    }
    $scope.getSelectedRows = function() {
        $scope.mySelectedRows = $scope.gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows();
    }
    $scope.headerButtonClick = function() {

        $scope.selectAll = $scope.grid.selection.selectAll;

    }
}
```

[Demo with    UI grid with infinite-scroll Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/6x5Q69AoK7b8sca2FZjv?p=preview)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score -2):

for large data set and multiple value drop down it is better to use `ng-options` rather than `ng-repeat`.

`ng-repeat` is slow because it loops over all coming values but `ng-options` simply display to the select option.

```
ng-options='state.StateCode as state.StateName for state in States'>
```

much much faster than

```
<option ng-repeat="state in States" value="{{state.StateCode}}">
    {{state.StateName }}
</option>
```

Comment: Did you check performance of ng-options? I'm trying to optimalize my code and it didn't help. Speed is the same as ng-repeat. -1

Comment: only works for select, ng-repeat is way more powerful. Nevertheless it's true that ng-Options is way faster than ng-repeat. AngularJs docs mentions 2000 items for differences: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select