# Please explain why angular ng-repeater decrease render performance as the number of rows increases

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have been observing the decrease in render performance of angular ng-repeater as number of rows increases

Here is my experiment. http://jsbin.com/quyofifa/1/edit?html,js,console,output

When you run the experiment you will find that  as number of rows increases time taken to render the row(DOM) increases. I measure this statistic by creating a directive which will execute when each row rendered and log time difference into console.

So here is my question why it is happening (internal detail) and how I can resolve this issue. I tried using filter **[limitTo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348058/how-to-improve-performance-of-ngrepeat-over-a-huge-dataset-angular-js)** but I could not find satisfactory result although it may a solution to pagination.

Comment: Same as you can finish reading a page of the book faster than reading the whole book...

Comment: That does look wrong though. If it really took an average of 90ms to load each row, it would have taken 50 seconds to write them all. But the JSBin has taken less than a couple seconds to load all the rows.

Comment: @zsong that's not exactly the same, because you have some average time per page. and the time increases per page in his example.

Comment: @Premchandra I think it's probably a problem with the implementation. the refTime isn't updated properly. so i made an edit to your implementation: http://jsbin.com/quyofifa/4/edit this one displays for every row around 0 to 1ms.

Comment: right, if you comment out `//$scope.refTime = (new Date()).getTime();` get same results, demo is measuring elapsed time

Comment: @RaphaelMüller I can't exactly say which implementation, mine or your is correct, may be your implementation is correct referring to charlietfl's way. Updating $scope.refTime makes angular busy to do his work resulting more delay, that become another point of discussion. But what I observed in my app is that when I used large number of complex object I find significant delay in rendering the item at higher index than rending starting item in the collection.

Comment: This is my actual log after I modified my directive as @RaphaelMüller tried

`Time taken to render row - 0 : 1029
Time taken to render row - 1 : 6 ms
Time taken to render row - 2 : 8 ms
Time taken to render row - 3 : 8 ms
Time taken to render row - 4 : 10 ms


Time taken to render row - 199 : 251 ms 
Time taken to render row - 200 : 241 ms 

Time taken to render row - 716 : 1053 ms
Time taken to render row - 717 : 1055 ms`

Unfortunately problem still persist. 

**One more point I am pushing record into collection as data received from data source**