# AngularJS long list with ng-repeat perfomance issue

Tags: angularjs, performance, typescript, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have searched for an answer but haven't found one, how to solve a performance issue with angular?
Without third party libraries like:

A) ReactJs
B) other libraries...

```
export class ReportController implements ng.IScope {
     public contacts: Array<string> _contacts;
     private _scope: ng.IScope;

     constructor( $scope:  ng.IScope ) {
        this._scope = $scope;

        this._contacts = this.getContacts(); // return 15k result
     }
}
```

By the way: track by NOT WORKING! not fast enough.

Comment: how do you expect people to help you out ? you didn't provide any piece of relevant code or description of what you are doing.

Comment: Have you tried `track by $index`?

Comment: Could you please add your code? It will be useful to give you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Going on a limb here, since you tagged it with `ng-repeat`, you want to look into once-only bindings if your data doesn't change, e.g. [this blog post](http://www.williambrownstreet.net/blog/2013/07/angularjs-my-solution-to-the-ng-repeat-performance-problem/) (and [the linked SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348058/how-to-improve-performance-of-ngrepeat-over-a-huge-dataset-angular-js)) has a good overview in addition to [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding).

Comment: Note: The link to 'Angular Using Track By' example in that article does not actually use `track by`, for track by example see: http://plnkr.co/edit/ACBZBJTkB4w8c6CH0ZxT?p=preview