# What is the best way for updating angular ng-repeat data values between view and controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to update data for ng-repeat between view and controller? If I put:

```
ng-repeat="item in actions"
```

And if I change $scope.actions in controller to some other value, would it be updated in ng-repeat? Is this the best way to update data values for ng-repeat between view and controller?

Comment: Yes. To both your questions. I'll expand on that a bit by saying the use of `track by` could make DOM rendering more efficient, depending on your usage (note: you can track by an array if `$index` may be inconsistent and your objects have composite keys). http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2556-using-track-by-with-ngrepeat-in-angularjs-1-2.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng-repeat is slow, you will know when you have good amount of data to start researching about better performance of ng-repeat.

You first question

> if I change $scope.actions in controller to some other value, would it
>   be updated in ng-repeat?

Yes, however if it doesn't work use angular's '$timeout'

```
$timeout(function(){
  $scope.actions = [];
},0)
```

Your second question

> Is this the best way to update data values for ng-repeat between view
>   and controller?

it is the best way though it is suggested supplementing ng-repeat with
[limitTo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) together with [Infinite scrolling](http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/).

Take a look [at this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348058/how-to-improve-performance-of-ngrepeat-over-a-huge-dataset-angular-js)