# Make sure DOM changes are finished before transition

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ng-animate

**Short version**

When ui-router transitions to a new view (using ngAnimate in some way that I don't fully understand), it adds the classes `ng-leave` and `ng-leave-active` to the the current view. It also adds the classes `ng-enter` and `ng-enter-active`to the next view. The problem is that the transition is started before all the DOM changes in the next view are finished, causing the transition to be choppy. So my question is; is it possible to prevent that the `ng-enter` and `ng-enter-active` classes are added until I decide that they should be added (by transmitting an event from a controller, or such)?

**Long version**

I am developing an AngularJS application which uses ui-router and ng-animate for transitions. I have run into a small performance problem, which I really would like to resolve to make the application run smoother.

The transitions between states seem to be stuttering, and I've found out that this is *probably* because during the transition Angular is performing DOM-changes while the transition is taking place.

How can I make sure that the DOM changes in the next view is finished before making the transition? I am using ui-router's resolve function together with promises that prevents the transition from taking place before the data is loaded.

I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eD3MU/341/) that illustrates my problem. When clicking the link to enter state2, it takes a while for the resolve rows to resolve with data (just as expected). However, it doesn't seem like the DOM is ready when the transition takes place, since the transition can be quite laggy. This makes me think that the DOM is not ready when the transition takes place.

*app.js*

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'ngAnimate'])
.config(['$stateProvider',  
    function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('state1', {
                url: '',
                views: {
                    'main': {
                        templateUrl: "state1.html",
                        controller: function(){

                        }
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('state2', {
                url: '/state2',
                views: {
                    'main': {
                        templateUrl: "state2.html",
                        controller: function($scope, rows){
                            $scope.rows = rows;
                        },
                        resolve: {
                            rows: function($q){
                                var rows = [];
                                var deferred = $q.defer();

                                for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
                                    rows.push({a: i, b: i/2, c: 3*i/2});
                                }

                                deferred.resolve(rows);

                                return deferred.promise;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    }])
```

*templates*

```
<div ui-view="main" class="main"></div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="state1.html">
    <a ui-sref="state2">Go to state 2</a>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="state2.html">
    <a ui-sref="state1">Back to state 1</a>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>b</th>
            <th>c</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
            <td>{{row.a}}</td>
            <td>{{row.b}}</td>
            <td>{{row.c}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</script>
```

*css*

```
.main{
    transition: all 1s ease;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.main.ng-enter{
    transform: translateX(30%);
    opacity: 0;
}

.main.ng-enter.ng-enter-active{
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
}

.main.ng-leave{
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
}

.main.ng-leave.ng-leave-active{
    transform: translateX(-30%);
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey Anton, can you be a little more specific about your elements and when it is happening? Maybe some code would help!

Comment: Hi @bobleujr! I have update my question with both code an a link to a JSFiddle!

Comment: I have update the question again with a shorter version of my problem!

Comment: I have few solutions, trying to see what you came up with already. 
Listening to transition events + ng-if is one.
Another are the events.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is `ng-repeat`. It creates a watch for each element, so as the number of elements increase the performance degrades. More than 2000-3000 elements will definitely impact performance of `ng-repeat`.

If you really need to display large number of rows using ng-repeat, then I would suggest go for: 
1. pagination
2. Infinite scroll using `limitTo` filter.

You can look here for reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17350875/5052704

Hope this helps!!

Comment: The ng-repeat and the number of elements isn't the main problem. I don't want it to start the transition before the DOM is finished with the changes. And it shouldn't matter how the content is created. I can make my controller broadcast an event or so whenever the DOM is ready, but I need that nganimate doesn't add the ng-enter-active class before I say that it should do so

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5053) is what i got after scrapping angular github issues. I feel that by using feat($animate) would resolve this problem by implying with close callback.Would you mind trying it as per the suggestion in link ? I will try to build plunker with it once i get some time in between.

Comment: That looks like it could be something, gotta look deeper into it!