# ng-repeat bind certain no. of records

Tags: angularjs

I am new in angular.js

I am dealing with large no.of records like 70,000 
i have to bind all record in one grid it takes to much time for binding.

for paging i am using dir-pagination is there any possibility in dir-pagination or ng-repeat that first only bind 100 records if i am going to change my page another records are bind.and when i am going to search , filter will apply to all records. 
for search functionality, i have all records in client side so that server-side paging is not possible for my case

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use itemsPerPage: 100 in dir-paginate directive

Comment: This might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348058/how-to-improve-performance-of-ngrepeat-over-a-huge-dataset-angular-js

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816073/how-to-do-paging-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

You should load different pieces of data based on your page number:

```
<paging-directive ng-model="currrentPage" ng-change="newPage">

<div ng-repeat="item in items"> 
  <div>{{item.data}}</div>
</div>
```

and in your controller:

```
var allData = []; //70000 items;

$scope.currentPage = 1;

$scope.newPage = function(){
  $scope.items = allData.slice(($scope.currentPage - 1)*100, $scope.currentPage *100);
};

$scope.newPage();
```

Comment: agree with your answer but in my table there is also search functionality so if i search something the filter will apply only in items array not in allData array.                                                                                           is there any possibility that i am filtering in allData record ?