# multiple ng-repeat in table row and columns hangs for 1000 records

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using ng-repeat to display the table-rows. Browser is not responsive when i load 1000 rows to that variable. That means validationRows  contains 1000 rows means page performance is not good. have to improve the performance in ng-repeat. I have checked the below link

[How to improve performance of ngRepeat over a huge dataset (angular.js)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348058/how-to-improve-performance-of-ngrepeat-over-a-huge-dataset-angular-js)

I don't want to use limitTo filter because i want to dispay entire records in same page at same time. I want to know how to use one -way binding in below code. Any other suggestion to improve the performance of ng-repeat.

```
<tbody> 
<tr ng-repeat="row in validationRows | orderBy:orderByField:sortReverse" class="dataRow" validate-data-loaded-all>
                                <td ng-repeat="column in validationColumns" ng-show="!$first" ng-class="highlight(row,column)">{{row[column]}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Why even load all `1000` rows - can the client see all 1000 rows at once? If the answer is no - then load the rows incrementally on scroll.

Comment: Is it slow to load, **or** slow to render, **or** slow to navigate the page once it is rendered?

Comment: I't is normal that the browser goes slow rendering 1000 records, that happens with datatables and jQuery too. I don't think it's a problem with ng-repeat performance but with the browser itself. I highly engourage you to use AJAX pagination, either scrolling or with regular pagination buttons below the table.

Comment: @tymeJV yes you are right. Is there any other better suggestion like paging ?

Comment: @mjwatts the browser is not responsive, it is taking 50-60 seconds to render the page

Comment: @Alvaro yes that is normal fact only. Is there any other better way to show huge records in table like paging ?

Comment: @SivaRajini I can't think of any. I recommendo you to use scroll pagination. In the beginning show a moderate numbe of records (let's say 50-100) and when te user scrolls down load 50 more (for example) and append them to the end of the table. Do this indefinitely until you have loaded all the records. This would be the same as Mushin is suggesting in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Infinite scroll](https://github.com/sroze/ngInfiniteScroll).By using this module you can load all the rows based on scroll.

This [Example](https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/demo_basic.html) will help you

Comment: thanks for your response. I will try this and let see how it works

Comment: @SivaRajini Glad to help you