# ng-repeat issue with huge data set

Tags: angularjs

I'm having 15,000 rows and want to display all the rows in a single page with or without pagination

Currently we are using ng-repeat and calling push when every record is being iterated.

I come across this link [How to improve performance of ngRepeat over a huge dataset (angular.js)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348058/how-to-improve-performance-of-ngrepeat-over-a-huge-dataset-angular-js)

I don't want to use infinite scrolling as we have search and filters which needs to be done on the same page on the whole data set.

Could you please some suggestion or how to improve the peformance? Currently it takes a minute to load the records.

Thanks.

Comment: https://tech.small-improvements.com/2013/09/10/angularjs-performance-with-large-lists/

Comment: Try using one time binding `{{:: }}` where ever possible to reduce the number of watchers; this might help a bit with performance. Also use `ng-if` instead of `ng-hide` in case you have used it _just for the sake of hiding/showing details_

Comment: Anyway, you should be going for pagination as 15000 records are not at all readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`limitTO`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) filter, which will limit the dataset that needs to be displayed on the view,

And have a scroll event or button to load more results

```
 <div ng-repeat="datobj in data | limitTo:1000">{{datobj}}</div>
```

Comment: will it work when we need to search the whole records or it search only the displayed records?

Comment: This doesn't work as it searches only on the displayed records